# How to create a single pdf containing multiple invoices

Tags: jasper-reports

I feed an xml file to *JasperReports* in order to generate a single invoice. This works fine.

However, I would also like to generate multiple invoices (i.e. all invoices for a given user) from a single xml file. The output should be just a single pdf file.

The XML file looks like this

`<orders>
   <order>
   ...
   </order>
   <order>
   ...
   </order>
   <order>
   ...
   </order>
</orders>`

Is this possible with *JasperReports* by just editing the jrxml file? I know that I could generate a pdf for each invoice by calling *JasperReports* in a loop. But I'd like to avoid this since it would require modifing a lot of code.

**Update**

I use the Jasper-Rails plugin for RoR to generate the reports. https://github.com/fortesinformatica/jasper-rails/blob/master/lib/jasper-rails/jasper_reports_renderer.rb

An xml for a single invoice is simply `<order> ... </order>`

The jrxml (note: xPath has already been changed to reflect mkl's approach) http://pastebin.com/R0vnrQgU

Comment: Most likely it is possible as you can iterate through those `order` elements in a XML data source.

Comment: @mkl Do you have any idea for what keywords I should be looking for on google?

Comment: That is hard to say because you neither show the JRXML to change nor do you indicate what exactly happens while you *feed an xml file to JasperReports in order to generate a single invoice*. Does any preprocessing occur, or are certain required properties added? ... Furthermore I'm not even sure how exactly the XML file for a *single* invoice looks like, is it simply `<order>...</order>` (`order` is the document element) or is it `<orders><order>...</order></orders>` (a single `order` element in an `orders` document element)? O something else altogether?

Comment: @mkl I edited my post to reflect your questions

Comment: Ok. I don't know that RoR integration, I'm living on the Java side. I assume, though, that plugin is generic enough to also support your changed use case. Concerning the JRXML, on the other hand, I still wonder whether it essentially generates the report by working on exactly one main data set or whether the main data sets are something else. In the former case a slight change of the field definitions may suffice. In the latter case, major re-working of the script may be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to generate a single PDF with multiple invoices if it before was possible to generate a PDF for a single invoice.

It is not clear how many changes to the JRXML are required. Unfortunately the OP did not provide a JRXML. To illustrate a simple case:

If the `order` merely contains some static amount of data and the JRXML, therefore, only essentially works on one data set, there is hardly anything to change. e.g.:

Let's assume you have original XMLs similar to this sample:

```
<order>
  <name>Mr. Smith</name>
  <quantity>2</quantity>
  <item>bike</item>
  <price>200</price>
</order>
```

and an original JRXML similar to this sample:

```
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/order]]>
</queryString>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quantity]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="item" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[item]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="price" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="aggregated" class="java.lang.Number">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{quantity}) * java.lang.Float.parseFloat($F{price})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="535" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Dear " + $F{name} + ","]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="40" width="235" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{item}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="335" y="40" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="75" width="535" height="35"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Please pay " + $V{aggregated} + " soon."]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="435" y="40" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{aggregated}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Now for multi-invoice XMLs like this sample:

```
<orders>
  <order>
    <name>Mr. Smith</name>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <item>bike</item>
    <price>200</price>
  </order>
  <order>
    <name>Mr. Fisher</name>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
    <item>box</item>
    <price>10</price>
  </order>
</orders>
```

all you have to do in the JRXML is to change the xPath expression to match all `order` elements and add a page break between data sets:

```
...
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[//order]]>
</queryString>
...
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        ...
        <break>
            <reportElement x="0" y="124" width="535" height="1"/>
        </break>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Even if the `order` contains more dynamic data, e.g. a variable number of items, it might be just as easy as long as the order element defines the main data set (the variable number of items might be handled by some table element working on a subdataset).

### Update

After the OP provided his JRXML file, it turns out that it essentially is of the simple type indicated above. A small correction is required, though:

The OP's JRXML uses only two sections, *Title* and *Page Footer*. The latter indeed is used for page footer material but the former is not used for a title but instead for the actual invoice body, i.e. for material which shall be printed not once (as a title) but as many times as there are data sets! To make this ready for multi-invoice outputs, therefore, the *title* band first has to be moved to become a *detail* band:

```
...
</background>
<title>
    <band height="616" splitType="Stretch">
        ...
    </band>
</title>
<pageFooter>
...
```

becomes

```
...
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="616" splitType="Stretch">
        ...
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
...
```

And due to the sheer size of this band, this already suffices to make the JRXML ready for multi-`order` inputs: A page break occurs automatically before the next *detail* section with information for the next data set because not more than one of these bands fits on a page and the band `splitType` is "Stretch".

Comment: This looks very promising! It seems to exactly match my jrxml. Will tr y this later today and report back.

Comment: I can't get it to work. The <break> is nowhere accepted in my jrxml by Jasper. I've updated my question with a link to the jrxml.

Comment: Your JRXML uses the *title* section for data set details. Making that section a *detail* section instead (*title* sections are used only once, detail sections are filled once per data set) allows use with multi-`order` inputs, cf. my update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The output into a single pdf isn't the point.
The key is how to use page breaks for each invoice and the use of the headers/bands, I think.